# Which editing and removing row method is better for JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I wanna ask that which method to edit a JTable is better than the other?

1. use setValueAt() function.
2. Make a new model of JTable and feed its object to JTable.

And also, how to remove a Row from JTable without using method 2 described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the setValueAt method when you're changing one value at a time.

You would make a new TableModel when you're changing 25% or more of the rows at one time.

If you use a [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) as your TableModel, you can use the addRow or setValueAt methods to add a row and change a row value.  You can use the removeRow method to remove a row.

Since the TableModel is associated with the JTable, any changes to the TableModel are reflected in the JTable.  Any changes to the JTable by the user are reflected in the TableModel.